# How to operate with only one array in composition API Vue 3

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, computed-properties

I'm new in vue 3, and I need your help. I created vue app that uses rest API to fetch the data. Also I added the features as filter and search to my application. But when I use filter or search function, it creates another computed arrays. First array is data, another is filteredData and third is filterByDate. Please, can you tell me, how to operate only with one araay in an app. Thanks in advance!
There is a code of my component.

```
<template>
  <Loading v-if="isLoading" />
  <AsteroidLayout
    v-else
    :data="data"
    :fetchData="fetchData"
    :plusDay="plusDay"
    :changeDay="changeDay"
  >
    <div class="inputWrapper">
      <input
        type="text"
        class="search"
        placeholder="Search an asteroid by name"
        v-model="searchQuery"
      />
    </div>
    <button @click="sorted = !sorted">Filter by close approach date</button>
    <div v-if="sorted" v-for="asteroid in filterByDate" :key="asteroid.name">
      <Asteroids :asteroid="asteroid" />
    </div>
    <div v-for="asteroid in filteredData" :key="asteroid.id">
      <Asteroids :asteroid="asteroid" />
    </div>
  </AsteroidLayout>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import { addDays } from "date-fns";
import { computed } from "vue";
import Loading from "../components/Loading.vue";
import AsteroidLayout from "../components/AsteroidLayout.vue";
import Asteroids from "../components/Asteroids.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    Loading,
    AsteroidLayout,
    Asteroids,
  },
  setup() {
    const API_KEY = "Kzb0E64htPxZGEM33UC62hrug7mfHAzEzIH8Qyu1";
    const data = ref([]);
    const isLoading = ref(false);
    const sorted = ref(false);
    const plusDay = ref(0);
    const searchQuery = ref("");
    onMounted(() => {
      fetchData(data.value);
    });
    const fetchData = (type) => {
      isLoading.value = true;
      data.value = type;
      fetch(
        `https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?end_date=${getDate()}&&api_key=${API_KEY}`
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          let fetchedData = res.near_earth_objects[getDate()];
          data.value = fetchedData;
          isLoading.value = false;
        })
        .catch(() =>
          alert(
            "Sorry, we can't load the asteroids data. Please try again later or check your internet connection"
          )
        );
    };

    const getDate = () => {
      return `${addDays(new Date(), plusDay.value).toISOString().substring(0, 10)}`;
    };

    const changeDay = (day) => {
      plusDay.value += day;
      fetchData(data.value);
    };
    const filteredData = computed(() => {
      return data.value.filter((asteroid) => {
        return asteroid.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery.value.toLowerCase()) != -1;
      });
    });
    const filterByDate = computed(() => {
      return data.value.sort((a, b) => {
        return (
          Date.parse(new Date(a.close_approach_data[0].close_approach_date_full)) -
          Date.parse(new Date(b.close_approach_data[0].close_approach_date_full))
        );
      });
    });
    return {
      data,
      isLoading,
      fetchData,
      plusDay,
      changeDay,
      filteredData,
      searchQuery,
      filterByDate,
      sorted,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.inputWrapper {
  text-align: right;
}

.search {
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid var(--secondary);
  border-radius: 35px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

And there is a screenshot of the vue devtools
[image]

Comment: what you mean by ` how to operate only with one araay in an app` what are you trying to do?

Comment: Computed method creates other arrays, when I use filter and search function. I need only one array (in my case, data array), and do all changes only in this array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just 1 computed prop for your `searchQuery`

You can try this instead

```js
const filteredData = computed(() => {
      let modifiedData = data.value;
      
      if(sorted.value){
        modifiedData = modifiedData.sort((a, b) => {
          return (
             Date.parse(new Date(a.close_approach_data[0].close_approach_date_full)) -
             Date.parse(new Date(b.close_approach_data[0].close_approach_date_full))
          );
        });
      }

      if(searchQuery.value !== ''){
        modifiedData =  modifiedData.filter((asteroid) => {
          return asteroid.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery.value.toLowerCase()) != -1;
        });

      }
     
     return modifiedData;
});
```

In HTML

```html
<div v-for="asteroid in filteredData" :key="asteroid.name">
    <Asteroids :asteroid="asteroid" />
</div>
```

This way you have sorted as well as filtered data according to `searchQuery` and all modifications are on original `data` which you received from api.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need to filter the data by click on button. I mean, filter must be toggled to button, and search to input

Comment: so it depends on `sorted` and `searchQuery` ? You can just add 1 more condition. Edited my answer